# Do Sql Update Statements run at the same time if requested at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

If two independent scripts call a database with update requests to the same field, but with different values, would they execute at the same time and one overwrite the other?

as an example to help ensure clarity, imagine both of these statements being requested to run at the same time, each by a different script, where Status = 2 is called microseconds after Status = 1 by coincidence.

```
Update My_Table SET Status = 1 WHERE Status= 0;
Update My_Table SET Status = 2 WHERE Status= 0;
```

What would my results be and why? if other factors play a roll, expand on them as much as you please, this is meant to be a general idea.

Side Note:
Because i know people will still ask, my situation is using MySql with Google App Engine, but i don't want to limit this question to just me should it be useful to others. I am using Status as an identifier for what script is doing stuff to the field. if status is not 0, no other script is allowed to touch it.

Comment: this **might** differ depending on the RDBMS being used, you should tag your question with your RDBMS (which sounds like mysql based on the body of the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what locking is for.  All major SQL implementations lock DML statements by default so that one query won't overwrite another before the first is complete.

There are different levels of locking.  If you've got row locking then your second update will run in parallel with the first, so at some point you'll have 1s and 2s in your table.

Table locking would force the second query to wait for the first query to completely finish to release it's table lock.

You can usually turn off locking right in your SQL, but it's only ever done if you need a performance boost and you know you won't encounter race conditions like in your example.

**Edits based on the new `MySQL` tag**

If you're updating a table that used the `InnoDB` engine, then you're working with row locking, and your query could yield a table with both 1s and 2s.

If you're working with a table that uses the `MyISAM` engine, then you're working with table locking, and your update statements would end up with a table that would either have all 1s or all 2s.

Answer (score 2):

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-restrictions.html (MySql)

> Normally, you do not need to lock tables, because all single UPDATE statements are atomic; no other session can interfere with any other currently executing SQL statement. However, there are a few cases when locking tables may provide an advantage:

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx (sql server)

> An UPDATE statement always acquires an exclusive (X) lock on the table it modifies, and holds that lock until the transaction completes. With an exclusive lock, no other transactions can modify data.

If you were having two separate connections executing the two posted update statements, whichever statement was started first, would be the one that completed.  THe other statement would not update the data as there would no longer be records with a status of 0

Comment: `update` acquires an [exclusive] update lock *on the resource it is modifying.* The scope of the lock, depending on what SQL implementation you are using and many other factors, might be 1 or more *rows*, *pages*, or the entire table. The scope of the lock(s) acquired will escalate as more and more locks are taken by the running process (e.g., once the number of locks hits the escalation threshold, the row locks are escalated to page locks. Once the page lock count hits its escalation threshold, the locks are escalated to a table lock. Read your documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: it depends on which statement commits first. Just because one process started an `update` statement before another doesn't mean that it will *complete* before another. It might not get scheduled first, it might be blocked by another process, etc.

Ultimately, it's a race condition: the operation that completes (and commits) last, wins.

Comment: What do you mean by the operation that completes ***last*** wins?  Isn't it the other way around, the first to complete is the one that wins? Because the 2nd update will not be able to see or update the row anymore...

Comment: In your specific case, that's true. In general, last wins.

Comment: Your saying it may be the case that because 2 runs after 1, it may overwrite 1 because of how the statement is worded. what if there was, say 300 records, and i post a limit 200 on both of those. would i have 100 0's and 200 2's?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have TWO scripts doing the same thing and using different values for the UPDATE, they will NOT run at the same time, one of the scripts will run before even if you think you are calling them at the same time. You need to specify WHEN each script should run, otherwise the program will not know what should be 1 and what should be 2.

Comment: oddly enough, the reason i have this problem is because i cant specify when that easily. if i could specify when with a high degree of accuracy, i would not have this issue, because i could force 1 and 2 to never run within even 30 seconds of each other, but GAE does not have that level of control. so i end up with sporatic start times that may end up being at the exact same time, and i dont have control over that.